# how to prevent exported environment variables to be recognized/accessible by a child shell (bash)?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

So, I need to prevent loads of exported variables to be recognized by a child shell.

The problem is an application (Wine+UDK) won't build projects with too many (>65535) bytes on the environment, and mine has a lot (95323) after I use a project (ScriptEchoColor) that shares environment variables between any bash shells.

I can't find a command that will allow me to spawn a child shell that won't accept current environment variables and instead will just use the ones that are set on my user profile and on the system as a whole.

I tried many options shown at `bash --help`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `env` command to start a process with a clean environment. Here is an example:

```
env -i /bin/myprog
```

If you still need to export some variables, you can do so in the call:

```
env -i MYVAR=foo /bin/myprog
```

The env command is required by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/env.html).

Comment: perfect! indeed I had to set a few variables and was very simple like: `env -i WINEPREFIX=$WINEPREFIX PATH=$PATH wine UDK.exe editor` thx!

Answer (score 4):

`env -i somecommand` runs `somecommand` in an empty environment. You can put arguments after `somecommand`. If `PATH` is erased, you'll need to specify the full path to `somecommand`. Alternatively you can preserve `PATH` or set a different value.

```
env -i PATH="$PATH:/another/directory" somecommand
```

If you want to have the same environment that you would have after login, preserve just a few variables and load your `.profile` to set the rest. If you use a different login shell (bash with `.bash_profile`, csh with `.login`, etc.), adapt accordingly.

```
env -i HOME="$HOME" PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin USER="$USER" \
    sh -c '. ~/.profile; "$@"' _ somecommand
```

Alternatively, you may prefer to remove some variables from the environment. `env -u VAR1 -u VAR2 somecommand` removes `VAR1` and `VAR2` from the environment and runs `somecommand`. Under Linux, you can use `env -0 | tr '\n\0' '.\n' | sed 's/=.*//'` to produce a list the environment variables with one name per line, suitable for filtering. On other unix variants, `env | sed 's/=.*//'` does the same job, with the limitation that it may find false positives if some variables's values contain newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Issue `typeset +x variable_name...` or `declare +x variable_name...` command.
You can even use regular expressions for variable names, like `typeset +x ${!MY_VAR_*}`.